# How to dynamically change autolayout of uiviewconroller and redraw screen content in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

On beginning I have `UIViewController` which contains `3 subviews (navbar, UICollectionView, banner)` which are vertically aligned. And after touch gesture on `UICollectionViewCell` I want to change content of controller to 5 `subviews (navbar, segmented control, UICollectionView, toolbar, banner)` without navigation to another controller. I tried to do that with following steps but It doesn't work as I thought.

1. Add 2 new subviews to content view of controller
2. Add anchor constraints for new views
3. set `view.setNeedLayout(), view.layoutIfNeeded()`
4. and call `overriden method viewWillAppear`

But in my case controller layout after redraw isn't equal to my expectations (new subviews are overlaped by collection view). So I need to help how to do it in proper way. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Ideally you should not call viewWillAppear. Calling SetNeedLayout and layoutIfNeeded should be enough, but I guess you should check your constraints.

Comment: @SHN Before I did it also without calling inline `viewWillAppear` but with same bad result. Approach which you mentioned I'm using regularly and always it worked but I never used it for redrawing full content of controller but only for parts like cells or some subviews. But I will look at constraints again. Thanks

Comment: @SHN Finally it works as I wanted. I create layout only once at loading of controller and after that I'm changing only exact constraints and hidding/showing views based on needs. With this approach `view.setNeedLayout(), view.layoutIfNeeded()` worked as I expected.